# finding the first dates of items in a list using SQL

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, duplicates, ms-access-2010

I'm building a local database in Access 2010 from reports of customer accounts that need demographic information searched. Each week a new report is generated and the results are added to the list, however there is duplication each week in the listing for those accounts that have not been found yet. I have been able to create queries that will display accounts that have only shown up on one report, and queries to display accounts that show up on multiple reports. But I am trying to now create a query that will show when an account was first added to the listing.

The columns I am looking at would be named similar to this:

accountNum - account number

custName - name of the customer

reportDate - the date that the account was pulled to be searched

The end result would be a table that shows all the accounts that (for example) appeared on multiple reports, but appeared first on December 1st, Dec 8th, Dec 15th, etc...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation query:

```
select accountNum, custName, min(reportDate)
from reports
group by accountNum, custName;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you a list of all of the accounts that appear multiple times along with the first date that they were reported.

```
SELECT
    accountNum,
    custName,
    MIN(reportDate) AS firstReportDate
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    accountNum,
    custName
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```